# How to dynamically insert a page <title> into JSP template?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

*template.jsp*:

```
<jsp:include flush="true" page="/header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="ideas/${param.ID}.jsp" flush="true" />
<jsp:include flush="true" page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

So how to get each `parameterID`'s varying titles to show up when I go to each page?

Comment: Please show us your code work.

Comment: That's basically it. The param.ID just calls different HTML content sections.  What I'm wondering is how to get it to display the content sections title for each page.

Answer (score 2):

By default I believe that the JSP EL expressions, such as `${param.ID}` are page scoped. If you want to use `${param.title}` inside of one of your imported jsp files, then you need to use a broader scope, such as request.

For example:

```
<c:set var="pageTitle" scope="request" value="${param.title}"/>
<jsp:include flush="true" page="/header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="ideas/${param.ID}.jsp" flush="true" />
<jsp:include flush="true" page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

header.jsp

```
<head>
<title>${pageTitle}</title>
...
</head>
```